# Scrapy can't scrape a website

Tags: python, hyperlink, scrapy, scrape

I've been on it for a couple of days, but I still can't find the answer.
I am using scrapy (python) to scrape [this webpage](http://fr.hotels.com/search.do?destination=New+York&arrivalDate=13%2F04%2F2015&departureDate=15%2F04%2F2015&rooms=1&children%5B0%5D=2&searchParams.rooms%5B0%5D.numberOfAdults=2&searchParams.rooms%5B0%5D.childrenAges%5B0%5D=7&searchParams.rooms%5B0%5D.childrenAges%5B1%5D=7&searchParams.landmark=&searchParams.resolvedLocation=CITY%3A1506246%3AEXACT_RED%3AHIGH&destinationId=).

Here're my directories :

```
hotels/
|_ scrapy.cfg
|_ hotels/
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ items.py
  |_ pipelines.py
  |_ settings.py
  |_ spiders/
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ hotels_spyder.py
```

---

Content of items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class HotelsItem(Item):
  nameHotel = Field()
  idHotel = Field()
```

---

Content of hotels_spyder.py

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from hotels.items import HotelsItem

class HotelsSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "hotels"
allowed_domains = ["hotels.com"]
start_urls = ["http://fr.hotels.com/search.do?destination=New+York&arrivalDate=13%2F04%2F2015&departureDate=15%2F04%2F2015&rooms=1&children%5B0%5D=2&searchParams.rooms%5B0%5D.numberOfAdults=2&searchParams.rooms%5B0%5D.childrenAges%5B0%5D=7&searchParams.rooms%5B0%5D.childrenAges%5B1%5D=7&searchParams.landmark=&searchParams.resolvedLocation=CITY%3A1506246%3AEXACT_RED%3AHIGH&destinationId="]

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//h3[@class="hotel-name"]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = HotelsItem()
        type(item)
        item['nameHotel'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['idHotel'] = site.xpath('a/@id').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

---

Content of settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'hotels'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['hotels.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'hotels.spiders'
```

---

So all of this works properly. It does what I want (still I have to clean spaces and stuff).

But my final goal is to scrape american version of the website.
So I tried to replace the list named "start_urls" I have in hotels_spyder.py with this one : http://www.hotels.com/search.do?destination=New+York&arrivalDate=03%2F18%2F15&departureDate=03%2F20%2F15&rooms=1&children[0]=2&searchParams.rooms[0].numberOfAdults=2&searchParams.rooms[0].childrenAges[0]=7&searchParams.rooms[0].childrenAges[1]=7&searchParams.landmark=&searchParams.resolvedLocation=CITY%3A1506246%3AEXACT_RED%3AHIGH&destinationId=

And it doesn't work. I have checked source code of both links and it's the same. I really don't get why it doesn't work and it's been driving me crazy for a week.

Thank you in advance,
Phil

Comment: How does it not work? What errors do you get?

Comment: It can not work at the moment because the query that you give as a link specifies an arrival date before today so the page gives an error page.

Comment: You're right, it was an older version and I've edited my question. Still it doesn't work.
The point is that I don't get any error, but I don't have any output as well.

Comment: Maybe you enabled logging and log the stdout - please provide your `settings.py` file.

Comment: I've added it to the initial message.

Comment: try site.xpath('.//a/text()').extract() instead. also what does your log say?

Comment: @l3aronsansgland, please check the new `start_urls` provided in the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and checked if it is ok. Finally I realized that your `start_urls` for 
an English version should be different.

You used an url starting with *http://www.hotels.com...*. For getting the English version of the site you need the right prefix. In the crawl of the French version it was `fr`. For the English version it is `uk`.

Try the following `start_urls`. It works in my crawler:

`start_urls = ['http://uk.hotels.com/search.do?destination=New+York&arrivalDate=13%2F04%2F2015&departureDate=15%2F04%2F2015&rooms=1&children[0]=2&searchParams.rooms[0].numberOfAdults=2&searchParams.rooms[0].childrenAges[0]=7&searchParams.rooms[0].childrenAges[1]=7&searchParams.landmark=&searchParams.resolvedLocation=CITY%3A1506246%3AEXACT_RED%3AHIGH&destinationId=']`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'll need to get prices in dollars. And the only place where it's available in dollars is apparently on http://www.hotels.com/.

The confusing part is that it's working on http://fr.hotels.com or [uk.hotels.com](http://uk.hotels.com), but not on the american version http://www.hotels.com